# Check if database is used by another C# Application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, desktop-application

Is there a way to check if a SQL Server database (`.mdf` file) is opened/used by another C# application?

I am installing a C# application on multiple computers. These apps are using a single/same database. What I want is to determine if one of the apps is currently using or doing a query to the database. Is this possible?

Comment: SQL Server databases should be **attached to a server** - that's the way they function the best. Don't mess around with free-floating `.mdf` files - that's just asking for trouble ...

Comment: Why does the database have anything to do with this.  If you want a single instance application, that requirement is better implemented without database knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the system stored procedure `sp_who2`.

Once you get the result filter by your database name. You can get the application name "ProgramName" column.

Run below SQL statement in sql server management studio,

```
exec sp_who2
```

Comment: Though a fine answer, will that tell you if its a _"c# application"_ though?

Comment: yes. run the sp, it'll return the application name in "ProgramName" column.

Comment: Only if the application is passing a name in the connection string.

Comment: if .net app does not the name in connection string, then it shows ".Net ...." as a application name.